# Highcharts polygon with no fill

Tags: highcharts

How can I create a Highcharts polygon plot with border line but without fill?

```
$(function() {

  $('#container').highcharts({
    series: [{
      name: 'Target',
      type: 'polygon',
      data: [
        [153, 42],
        [149, 46],
        [149, 55],
        [152, 60],
        [159, 70],
        [170, 77],
        [180, 70],
        [180, 60],
        [173, 52],
        [166, 45]
      ]
    }],
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s3zp8cce/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `scatter` series type:

```
series: [{
  type: 'scatter',
  lineWidth: 2,
  data: [...]
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4874/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter.lineWidth